# installing msodbcsql failed on linux cause of depends on libcurl3

Tags: sql-server, odbc, libcurl, php-curl, php-7.2

In my Debian system used php7.2.4-1, I would connect sqlserver in my project. however, it return failed installing `msodbcsql` which depends on `libcurl3` . And it is `libcurl4` in my debian system.

I try to install `libcurl3` and the reason is that the php7.2-curl is not work.

```
php7.2 depends on libcurl4
msodbcsql or msodbcsql17 depends on libcurl3
```

So can I install both `libcurl3` and `libcurl4`? Or is there any other way around?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So your issue is that you are trying to mix stretch and buster packages, and there is a libcurl version transition across that upgrade.

- [msodbcsql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) is available for stretch.
- php7.2 is available for buster, stretch has php7.0.
- msodbcsql depends on libcurl3, available in both stretch and buster.
- php7.2 depends on libcurl4 which is only available for buster.
- libcurl3 and libcurl4 conflict, for reasons I'll expand on.

Mixing stretch and buster packages is very possible but considered unsupported by Debian due to occasional issues like this. The third party msodbcsql package is also unsupported.

### Option 1: Avoid msodbcsql

If you just want to use odbc with PHP you probably don't need msodbcsql. The php-odbc package will do what you need.

### Option 2: Downgrade

The easy solution to avoid the conflicts would be to downgrade php to php7.0, available on stretch and using libcurl3. All conflicts go away.

### Option 3: Forced the dependency

Another solution is to download the msodbcsql package and force install it using

```
dpkg --ignore-depends=libcurl3 -i msodbcsql.deb
```

This will probably work in practice because the difference between libcurl3 and libcurl4 is a minor incompatible API change for a depreciated FTP function. As msodbcsql will probably not use that function there won't be any issues.

The Debian package manager will however complain bitterly, some options to fit that [how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies.](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies)

### Option 4: Containerise it

Finally, if you aren't using msodbcsql and PHP together then a container to keep the conflicts apart would be worth considering.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My solution now is to downgrade php version to `php7.1` which is the quickest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

In 7.2.9-1 for Ubuntu 16 the php-curl extension work with libcurl4.
You can simply download the php packages that are prepared for debian installation and manually install with APT. The previously installed packages will be downgraded/upgraded to the new version:

```
mkdir ./php7.7.9
cd php7.2.9

wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2_7.2.9-1_all.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-bz2_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-cli_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-common_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-curl_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-dev_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-fpm_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-gd_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-imap_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-intl_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-json_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-ldap_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-mbstring_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-mysql_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-opcache_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-readline_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-soap_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-xml_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-xmlrpc_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb
    wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php7.2/php7.2-zip_7.2.9-1_amd64.deb

    apt install ./*.deb
```